# malware and viruses

Tags: google-play-store

Are applications downloaded from Play Store are not completely safe as Android is developed by Google and is based on Linux so they do not watch applications an end user is downloding why we need to have a malware or virus scanner

Comment: Who says you need an virus scanner on Android (except for those companies that sell those tools)?

Comment: [Food for thought](https://raccoon.onyxbits.de/blog/android-app-developer-spam-filter/)

Comment: [Google can take two months to remove malware apps from app store](https://www.newscientist.com/article/2286931-google-can-take-two-months-to-remove-malware-apps-from-app-store/). You can also search for "Google removed malware from Play Store" to see other occurences.

Comment: Do you have anti-virus to protect Ubuntu?